# json extractor expression to extract field outside array

Tags: jmeter

How can I grab `productId` from the outside array after checking for the condition. I have tried `$..items[?(@.stock.available==true)].productId`

```
{
   "listings": [
       {
           "productId": "100-dark-hot-chocolate",
           "items": [
               {
                    "stock": {
                       "available": true
                   }
               }
           ],
           "test": null
       }
       
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This one should give you what you're looking for:

```
$.listings[*][?(@.items[0].stock.available == true)].productId
```

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [JsonPath - Filter Operators](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#filter-operators)
- [JMeter's JSON Path Extractor Plugin - Advanced Usage Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter)

Comment: Awesome. That works. Learn new things everyday!.